# How do I use lombok @Builder to store different values?

Tags: java, lombok

I have the following JPA entity

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Post {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  UUID id;

  @OneToMany
  Set<PostTags> tags;

  String content;
}

@Data
public class PostTag {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  UUID id;

  @OneToOne
  Post post;

  String tag;
}
```

Using lombok @Builder I want to be able to do the following

```
Post post = Post.builder()
  .tags("hello", "world")
  .content("Hello world")
  .build();
```

I am presuming I need a custom builder along the lines of

```
public static class PostBuilder {
  private Set<String> myTags = new HashSet<>();
  public PostBuilder tags(String... tags) {
    myTags.addAll(Arrays.asList(tags));
    return this;
  }
}
```

From the [documentation](https://www.projectlombok.org/features/Builder) it appears there `ObtainVia` annotation that I can use, but I am not sure how to get around it (no example on the doc) and especially since I only want `myTags` to be a builder specific thing, and not be exposed on the main class itself.

Answer (score 0):

`ObtainVia` only works for `toBuilder`, so that won't help much in this case.

I suggest the following approach.

First, add a factory method in `PostTag`, e.g. `createTag(String)`. This method only sets `tag` in the instance it creates and leaves everything else `null`. Statically import it into the class where you want to use `PostBuilder`.

Next, use `@Singular` on `tags`. Then you can write:

```
Post post = Post.builder()
   .tag(createTag("hello"))
   .tag(createTag("world"))
   .content("Hello world")
   .build();
```

Finally, customize the `build()` method so that it first creates the `Post` instance (like an uncustomized `build()` method would) and then sets this newly created `Post` instance as `post` in all `PostTag` instances.
Have a look at the `delombok`ed code to make sure you use the right builder class and method headers when customizing the builder.

Comment: i want to use string tags as parameters, but the underling collection is a PostTag not a String

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. How do you build an instance of `PostTag` from a string? Just set `tag` and leave everything else `null`?

Comment: I thought about that but because PostTag requires "Post" it sort of a chicken and egg problem

Comment: I updated my answer. Feel free to ask if something is not clear (or if I missed something again :-) ).

Comment: Thanks, but where does the PostTag get it's "post" value set?

Comment: In the customized `build()` method. I changed the wording to make clearer what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@Accessors`](https://www.projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors) for what you're asking:

**Post**

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<PostTags> tags;

    private String content;

    public Post tags(String... tags) {
        Arrays.stream(tags)
                .map(tag -> PostTags.builder().tag(tag).build())
                .forEach(this.tags::add);
        return this;
    }
}
```

**PostTags**

```
@Data
@Builder
public class PostTags {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    @OneToOne
    private Post post;
    private String tag;
}
```

When you using `@Accessors(chain = true)`, The setters will return `this` reference instead of `void`, and then your code will act this way:

```
Post post = new Post().setId(id).tags("aaa", "bbb");
```

If you want your code to be more similar to builder then add `fluent` value to the annotation: `@Accessors(chain = true, fluent = true)`

It will remove the `set<Something>` from the setters and just use the name of the fields, and then your code will look like this:

```
Post post = new Post().id(id).content("hello").tags("aaa", "bbb");
```